# How to read pdf file in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, file

I am getting data from web server as JSON, which include several fields. It also has one parameter named fileContent which contains string of raw value, that need to be encoded and save as pdf file. I have tried to use many encoding, however none of them are converting into exact file. Below is my code and JSON response.

```
do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
                    if let sample = json["fileContent"] as? String {
                        do {
                            // get the documents folder url
                            if let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
                                // create the destination url for the text file to be saved
                                let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("file.xlsx")
                                print(fileURL)
                                // define the string/text to be saved
                                // writing to disk
                                // Note: if you set atomically to true it will overwrite the file if it exists without a warning
                                try sample.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
                                print("saving was successful")
                                // any posterior code goes here
                                // reading from disk
                                let savedText = try String(contentsOf: fileURL)
                                print("savedText:", savedText)   // "Hello World !!!\n"
                            }
                        } catch {
                            print("error:", error)
                        }
                    }
                    
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }


{
    "version": "v1",
    "contentType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    "extension": "xlsx",
    "fileContent": "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",
    "size": 11997,
    "deleted": false,
    "file": true
}
```

Comment: It looks like it is encoded with base64.  You will need to decode the base64 string in order to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

refer answer given below:

How to display a base64 file | Apple Developer Forums https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/94337